# Firefox Flash settings enable /disable

Tags: firefox

i am trying to Enable/disable the firefox shockwave flash settings pragmatically in c#, but i don't know where those setting get saved on local machine.

does someone know the location where and in which file/registry key those settings get saved.

Comment: You can't do it: _In September 2019, Firefox 69 will remove the "Always Activate" Flash option so we always ask for user permission before activating Flash on a website._ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Roadmap - It means that there is no settings which would be persistent accross browser restarts.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information but as of for now Firefox still have Always Active option. So it means this option still exsits in the firefox. Is firefox forget to remove the option or will still continue to support it untill will stop the support for flash which is in 2020?

Comment: I would not rely on this. If you embed somehow firefox into your app for some rendering capabilities I would advice you to switch from flash to html5 until it is late (you will need to consider it anyway sooner or later). I do not advice you to switch on flash without user consent because it opens up attack vector on such user without him knowing it. Users will be mad with you when then know it.

Comment: I really need the registry key for firefox to enable the flash. its our requirement as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not stored in a registry.

**Short answer:**

create new file "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\autoconfig.js" and place following content into it:

```
// Any comment. You must start the file with a single-line comment!
pref("general.config.filename", "my-conf.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
```

also place my-conf.cfg file into top-level directory where FF is installed (i.e. C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\my-conf.cfg):

```
//keep comment at first line. it is important
lockPref("plugin.state.flash",2);
```

and use 0 to disable it:

```
//keep comment at first line. it is important
lockPref("plugin.state.flash",0);
```

**Explanation:**

Typically user preferences are stored in prefs.js file in theirs profile  and particular parameter is defined as:

```
pref("some.setting","setting-value");
```

Such definition of parameter allows user to change it.
To make change permanent (to block user's meddlings with parameter via GUI) you can lock it:

```
lockPref("some.setting","setting-value");
```

This file(prefs.js) is text file which can be edited by text editor.
You can set initial value for some parameter (or override it) but user is able to change these parameters in UI (about:config) and firefox will overwrite this file. If you modify this file while Firefox is running then most likely any tweaks/changes made to this file will be lost.

If you need to lock some parameter to some specific value and disallow user to change it then you need to define this definition [elsewhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment_before_60) and by lockPref statement.

Relevant information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences)

And in a corporate environment you can define(and lock) such setting at the level of [Domain Controller](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-group-policy-windows).

Comment: Thanks for reply Maxim. i have found the flash settings in pref.jis file and it worked.